# Issue with Apache Poi while Parsing excel in java?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using `Apache POI` to parse `excel` file and to get values back am doing by `row.getCell(5).getNumericCellValue()` assuming that `cell(5)` on that row would always be number.

Is it possible to intelligently parse file so that even if order of columns is changed or jumbled even then we can look for values based on `columnName` so that contract year always comes from the column labelled `Contract Year` - regardless of whether that column is the 6th or 7th column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement a function called `getContractYearColumnIndex()` which returns the index you need.

```
private int getContractYearColumnIndex(){
    final int maxColIndex = 25;
    int colIndex = 0;
    HSSFRow titleRow = yourSheet.getRow(0);
    String value = titleRow.getCell(colIndex).getStringCellValue();

    while(value != "Contract Year" && colIndex < maxColIndex){
        colIndex = colIndex + 1;
        value = titleRow.getCell(colIndex).getStringCellValue();
    }
    return colIndex;
}
```

Of course, this implementation supposes the title you're looking for is in the first row (index 0).

Comment: ok but the thing here is that file is configurable and so there are possibilities that row could be present or they could not be present no file

Comment: also this would add lots of processing load on the system right.

Comment: Yes, it will be a performance hit. Excel is not a good format to store structured data although I understand that you may be helpless, been in that situation :)

Comment: well call the function only once for the entire file and store the result in a variable so then you only have to call `row.getCell(contractYearIndex)`.

Comment: if you suppose the column may not be in the row, then set a limit to the `colIndex` variable (see edited answer).